# Why are Analysis Services and Reporting Services missing?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I have bought SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition and installed it on my PC at home. I also have Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition installed.

Here are the installed components:

[image]

I have installed SSDT. However, I only have the option to create an Integration Services project as shown below:

[image]

Where is the option for Analysis Services and Reporting Services?

Comment: Just a quick note: SSDT and SQL Server have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Can you verify you installed the SSDT from this link? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383

Answer (score 0):

you can go to SSMS and check if analysis services and reporting services are appearing on login.[image]

your visual studio installation has nothing to do with it. Once you open SSDT you should see following options.
[image]